# Converting existing vectors to Mahout Vectors

Tags: hadoop, mahout, lda, sequencefile

I"m trying to convert term-frequency values into mahout vector representation, so that I can use LDA on the given vectors. I'm following the mahout wiki where the code snippest suggest how to convert exisitng vectors to Mahout Vectors.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/creating-vectors-from-text.html

Here's my code, I'm getting a NullPointerException in the place of creating the VectorWriter. The apache cwiki suggests using,

```
VectorWriter vectorWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(filesystem, configuration, outfile, LongWritable.class, SparseVector.class);
```

But, I dont see the SequenceFile.createWriter in the org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;

This is the complete code segment.

```
        fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        //I"m using SeqeunceFile.Writer because SequenceFile.createWriter is not available.
        VectorWriter vectorWriter = (VectorWriter) new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf, path, LongWritable.class, RandomAccessSparseVector.class);

        ArrayList<Vector> weights = new ArrayList<Vector>();
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/hadoop/LDATest/LDAData/test"));
        String line = null;

        while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
        {    
            String[] data = line.split(" "); // split the term,weight data
            Vector weightVector = new RandomAccessSparseVector(1,1);
            weightVector.setQuick(0, Double.parseDouble(data[1])); // add the weight
            weights.add(weightVector);
        }


        vectorWriter.write(new VectorIterable(weights));
```

This the error,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.SerializationFactory.getSerializer(SerializationFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.init(SequenceFile.java:910)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.(SequenceFile.java:843)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.(SequenceFile.java:831)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Writer.(SequenceFile.java:823)
    at kbsi.ideal.LDATest.iterableTest(LDATest.java:161)
    at kbsi.ideal.LDATest.main(LDATest.java:194)

I really appreciate your help on this. Thanks